# ERD from SQL Server CE 4.0

Tags: visual-studio, database-design, sql-server-ce, diagram, erd

I'd like to auto-generate an ERD from a SQL Server CE 4.0 database. I don't know if it can be done, or what tool I would need.

The only tools I know of (or that I have) for opening a SQL Server CE 4.0 database is LINQPad and Visual Studio 2010. Evidently SSMS still can't open one. Anyway, LINQPad does not generate such diagrams, and Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate doesn't appear to have that ability in regard to a SQL Server CE database.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My SQL Server Compact toolbox can create a database diagram (DGML) - maybe you can use that? http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com

Comment: I made the DGML output with your tool, but it did not include relationship annotations between the tables.  I was hoping the foreign key relationships would be part of the model.  Did I do something incorrectly?

Comment: The DGML visualizes any foreign key relationsships - maybe you do not have any defined?